# Twitter Bootstrap - wrapping grid column problem

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with latest Twitter Bootstrap 4.5.  I'm migrating from previous version of TB where it was ok to do this:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="wrapper_1">
<div class="col-sm-6">Column A</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">Column B</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper_2">
<div class="col-sm-4">Column A</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">Column B</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">Column C</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The obvious scenario above would be client-side to hide/show wrapper_1 vs. wrapper_2.  However, TB now expects the div column element to be immediate child of the row so column layout is lost.  Is there a workaround for this?

Karl..

Answer (score 0):

Nesting is fully supported.  You have to be sure to maintain a .row .col arrangment as you nest so would change original code sample to:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div id="wrapper_1" class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">Column A</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">Column B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper_2" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">Column C</div>
  </div>
</div>
```